# .NET6 vs .NET Core 3.1 compatibility

Tags: compatibility, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1

Is it safe to have a .NET6 application which references a .NET Core 3.1 NuGet library?

I tested this case using a simple console application. Everything looks good and there are no errors/warning. However, I haven't found any specific information so prefer to make sure.

This is important, as one of my providers offers only a .NET Core 3.1 NuGet package. Knowing the company it'll take them a year or so to prepare a .NET6 / .NETStandard version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a good chance that your .NET Core 3.1 library will run without any compatibility problems as part of your .NET 6 application.

Quoting the .NET fundamentals article [Changes that affect compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/) (**emphasis mine**):

> Throughout its history, .NET has attempted to maintain a high level of
> compatibility from version to version and across implementations of
> .NET. …
>
> Along with compatibility across .NET implementations, developers
> expect a high level of compatibility across versions of a given
> implementation of .NET. **In particular, code written for an earlier
> version of .NET Core should run seamlessly on .NET 5 or a later
> version.** In fact, many developers expect that the new APIs found in
> newly released versions of .NET should also be compatible with the
> pre-release versions in which those APIs were introduced.

However, compatibility is not guaranteed. The article goes on to say:

> This article outlines **changes that affect compatibility** and the
> way in which the .NET team evaluates each type of change.
> Understanding how the .NET team approaches **possible breaking
> changes** is particularly helpful for developers who open pull
> requests that modify the behavior of existing .NET APIs.

Furthermore, in an answer to the question [Clarification on backwards compatibility of .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1959), a [member of the .NET runtime team](https://github.com/jkotas) says:

> **We do not guarantee 100% compatibility between major versions.** This is true for both ASP.NET Core and the runtime itself. We
> intentionally make breaking changes where we believe that they are
> necessary to move the platform forward and the cost of the .NET
> ecosystem adjusting to them is low enough.

Breaking changes that could *potentially* affect the compatibility of your .NET Core 3.1 library are those that are documented for [.NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0) and [.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/6.0).

But, if you are not experiencing any problems with your .NET Core 3.1 library, it would appear that none of the documented compatibility problems apply.

Ultimately, of course, you'll have a higher degree of confidence in the library when your vendor provides one that has been updated for .NET 6.

Finally, with the introduction of .NET 5, there became a [lesser need for .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0):

> .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are
> available on multiple .NET implementations. The motivation behind .NET
> Standard was to establish greater uniformity in the .NET ecosystem.
> **.NET 5 and later versions adopt a different approach to establishing uniformity that eliminates the need for .NET Standard in most
> scenarios.** However, if you want to share code between .NET Framework
> and any other .NET implementation, such as .NET Core, your library
> should target .NET Standard 2.0. [No new versions of .NET Standard will
> be released](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/), but .NET 5, .NET 6, and all future versions will continue
> to support .NET Standard 2.1 and earlier.

Comment: I think I owe you a coffee for this response. Remember that you are always welcome in my area ;).

Comment: Does this .NET Core 3.1 NuGet package require to keep the 3.1 runtime installed and, if so, wouldn't that be a security issue after end of support of the 3.1 runtime?

Comment: @R.Schreurs I don't have 3.1 runtime installed and it works, so either the answer is "no" or I'm extremely lucky.

Comment: @R.Schreurs Perhaps you are thinking of [In-Process Side-by-Side Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/in-process-side-by-side-execution)? "Starting with the .NET Framework 4, you can use in-process side-by-side hosting to run multiple versions of the common language runtime (CLR) in a single process." With .NET Core, a later version of the CLR is capable of loading DLLs built for an earlier version of .NET Core (or .NET Standard) and does not have a dependency on earlier versions of the CLR.

Comment: @R.Schreurs Also see: [.NET Core + .NET 4 In Process Side By Side Execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60424940/1497596)