# How to register AbpModule in .Net 6 Webapp

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I've a .net core 3.1 application downloaded using Aspnet boilerplate (https://aspnetboilerplate.com/). The project is using 5.1.0 version of Abp Nuget packages.

I've got different .net core 3.1 class libraries and each dll has it's own module inherited by AbpModule. And I registered the module in the startup file of main web project

```
 return services.AddAbp<MyModule>(
     options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
         f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
     )
 );
```

Now I want to add a new Empty web project that will only have one BackgroundService but I want to use .Net 6 for that. But I am struggling to find a way to register my module e.g MyModule in the Program.cs file of my project.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

I reviewed the AspNet Boilerplate documentation but couldn't find any useful information that would clarify whether it's possible or not. I believe that .NET 6 is backward compatible, so referencing .NET Core 3.1 DLL shouldn't be an issue. However, I'm unsure how to register the module in it. If it's not possible, I might consider downgrading to .NET Core 3.1

Comment: _" I believe that .NET 6 is backward compatible"_ [Not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72532363/net6-vs-net-core-3-1-compatibility) It may work, but it also may not. You may need to update your class libraries to target .NET Standard or use mutlti-targetting to target both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6.